# VueJS 3 - Passing prop to slot without reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I need to pass an object to a child slot, but that object will not be ready when the component is mounted and it absolutely cannot be a reactive because [webpack will do bad things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71210453/vuejs-3-webpack-trying-to-read-external-cssstylesheet-that-it-does-not-have-acc), even when it's a shallow reactive.

Short version: I got the google maps api (googlemaps/js-api-loader) all wired up with markers and clustered, and worked out all the bugs. Now I want to turn it into components and reuse it.

It was easy enough to wait for the map to be ready when it was all one component, but now I have markers in separate components (to allow easy layering/separate control of marker groups). Per the link above, I cannot make the map object reactive. However, the initial state is passed into children via properties, so it's always `undefined`.

Map component:

```
<template>
    <div class="map" ref="mapDiv"></div>
    <slot name="markers" :map="map" v-if="mapped"></slot>
</template>
```

Script `setup()`:

```
const mapDiv = ref();
const mapped = ref(false);
let map;

new Loader(props.loader).load().then((result) => {
    map = new window.google.maps.Map(mapDiv.value, props.options);
    mapped.value = true;
    return result;
});

return {mapDiv, map, mapped}
```

I thought to add the `v-if` and see if it would grab the latest value, but that still uses the initial undefined value of map that was returned. Which makes total sense.

Massive workaround, I can shove the reference in the global window object and poll, but that breaks the Vue pattern. I also need a per-instance reference of the map object, as there may be multiple map components, which becomes a juggling nightmare.

**The Question**

Is there a way to pass a non-reactive property within the Vue component setup? Even a way to pass it as a delayed action?

---

Deeper explanation:

Vue wants us to do this:

```
const mapDiv = ref();
const map = reactive({});

new Loader(props.loader).load().then((result) => {
    map.assign(new window.google.maps.Map(mapDiv.value, props.options));
    return result;
});

return {mapDiv, map}
```

But the moment you shove the map in a reactive, Vue explodes in errors. The map object is not compatible with the reactive proxy. Even with a `shallowReactive`, it tries to traverse properties that point to cross-site resources from google, which is a security issue: the browser has a meltdown and it just doesn't work.

As an example, this works as expected:

```
const mapDiv = ref();
const map = reactive({}); //<-- WORKS BECAUSE REACTIVE

new Loader(props.loader).load().then((result) => {
    Object.assign(map, {test: 'Hello, world!'});
    return result;
});

return {mapDiv, map}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to use reactive for an object unless what your really need is reactivity. For basic awareness of the object change passed down to child components, a `ref` or `shallowRef` will do:

```
const map = ref({});
map.value = new window.google.maps.Map(mapDiv.value, props.options);
```

Comment: `ref` is reactive too. The problem is primarily that you tried to clone map object with Object.assign. Classes aren't expected to behave correctly this way, reactive or not. As it was said in linked question, shallowRef is a safe choice if you don't want to mangle class instance.